# is it possible do a template with 3 different variables without overloading

Tags: c++, templates

In class, we learned templates and their usage but we took the example of max3:

```
template <typename T>
T max3(T x, T y, T z){
  if (x>y && x>z) return x;
  if (y>x && y>z) return y;
  return z;
}
```

and for 3 different types or two same one different type parameter we did this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
T1 max3(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
  std::cerr<<"erreur in max3"<<std::endl;
  std::terminate();
}
```

So is it possible to do a max3 with 2 same and one different parameter or do I have to overload to make sure that it works correctly?

Comment: have you tried `template <typename T1, typename T2> T1 max3(T1 x, T1 y, T2 z)`?

Comment: @George but so that means I have to convert them to the same type so that the first code I wrote works, I was trying to ask (I am working with primitive types) is it possible to write a template that does not need to take one type of variable but  can take 3 of them

Comment: @mch but doesn't it means that it will always want to return me a T1 type result? What if z is the max

Comment: @T.K -  Agree.   It'd potentially be even worse if `z` was the maximum of the three, and its value couldn't be stored in a `T1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::common_type` to get a type for the return value.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
std::common_type_t<T1, T2, T3> max3(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
  if (x>y && x>z) return x;
  if (y>x && y>z) return y;
  return z;
}
```

If you pass in for example `int`s and `float`s you will always get a float back even when one of the `int`s are higher. So the highest value will get converted to a float and returned.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your question.

```
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    T1 max3(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
            std::cerr<<"erreur in max3"<<std::endl;
            std::terminate();
     }
```

Will trigger regardless of types of `T1, T2, T3`, be all of them identical, all different, or two of three matching.

If in class it was claimed that adding following function helps:

```
    template <typename T>
    T max3(T x, T y, T z){
          if (x>y && x>z) return x;
          if (y>x && y>z) return y;
          return z;
    }
```

Then they are wrong. If all 3 types equal then neither definition has clear precedence leading to UB (it should've been an error though). Yeah, template functions are a mess.

Proper way is to define template functions that strictly do not overlap. Which is normally done via SFINAE:

```
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, std::enable_if_t<not (std::is_same_v<T1,T2> and std::is_same_v<T1,T3>),int> = 0>
    T1 max3(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
            std::cerr<<"erreur in max3"<<std::endl;
            std::terminate();
     }

    template <typename T>
    T max3(T x, T y, T z){
          if (x>y && x>z) return x;
          if (y>x && y>z) return y;
          return z;
    }
```

Here `std::enable_if_t` helped ensure that not all types are equal.

Comment: In class, we learned, first with only the first code that I wrote. Then our worksheet said that what happens if you put three different types or two same and one different type and the answer was that it did not work but after worksheet said to avoid confusion put a template that will give an error in the second case of the situation (3 different types or one different two same)  So our teacher wrote the second code. I asked my question to know if it possible to (with one template) compare 3 different types of numbers